# Draw Line on Google Map using C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google MAP Integration using C#. Now I wish to create Screen Line function. In short I just want to draw  between two points on a click event on Google Map.

Let me know if you need to detail on the problem.

Comment: You can draw lines using the API, and it's done in javascript.

Comment: Yes, this is done client side...

Comment: Any sample code to perform this operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do it using the Javascript API v3:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polylines

But it sounds like you may be using some sort of control that does it for you in C#. I'm going to guess because you haven't provided more information about what you are using to create the map, but let's assume you're using:

http://googlemap.codeplex.com/

(Which is a great Google Maps control for WebForms). This Control has a polyline extender which does what you need to, located here:

http://googlemap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GoogleMap%20Control%206.0&referringTitle=Documentation

Which is downloadable here:

http://googlemap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GooglePolyline6

There is information on the PolyLine class in their documentation here:

http://googlemap.artembg.com/docs/

If this doesn't answer your question, please provide more information about the Google Maps implementation you are using.